# Can rpmbuild ignore files in buildroot?

Tags: svn, rpm, rpmbuild

I have a target directory that is checked into svn.  I use the target as the --buildroot when I run rpmbuild.  This causes rpmbuild to loose it mind because of the .svn directories in each directory.  Is there a way to tell rpmbuild to relax?

I looked at svn export target target-build, but it only knows about files tracked by rpm.  Perhaps not a bad way to do it, but I'm not quite sure that is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is build the filelist during the install stage in rpm spec (ignoring the files you need to ignore), then use this file list in the %files section instead of just specifying the whole directory.

You can find a sample of this in the stock RedHat/CentOS php rpm - the part where php extensions are built.

Comment: But that still requires that any files left over are not in the buildroot.  I will take a look at the php rpm for some enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have overridden buildroot in the first place. Recent versions of rpm can automatically clean (i.e. do **rm -rf**) buildroot during rpm build process.

If nothing else you risk losing your work. And no, whatever rpm finds in buildroot it assumes it was put there during build and should be installed (i.e. something was forgotten in `%install` section).